# Combine th:each with templating element using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, templates, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf

I have a list of 'product' which I want to show as a list of row table using an html template.

The html template looks like:

```
<tr th:fragment="productTemplate">
    <td th:text="${productName}">product name</td>
    <td th:text="${productprice}>product price</td>
</tr>
```

Here is what I did:

```
<table>
  <tr th:each="product : ${products}" th:substituteby="product :: productTemplate" th:with="productName=*{name}, productPrice=*{price}" />
</table>
```

If I use `th:include`, there will be tr nested to each `tr`
If I use `th:substituteby`, substitute has the priority on `th:each`

I cant find a way to replace my loop items by an other.

Somebody have a solution to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got it:

```
<table>
  <tr th:each="product : ${products}" th:include="product :: productTemplate" 
      th:with="productName=${product.name}, productPrice=${product.price}" 
      th:remove="tag" />
</table>
```

And here, we can keep the template class on the **tr** element (that what I wanted)

```
<tbody th:fragment="productTemplate">
  <tr class="my-class">
    <td th:text="${productName}">product name</td>
    <td th:text="${productPrice}">product price</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

here's the result:

```
<table>
  <tr class="my-class">
    <td>Lettuce</td>
    <td>12.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="my-class">
    <td>Apricot</td>
    <td>8.0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

thanks to [danielfernandez](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=316889) from the [official thymeleaf forum](http://forum.thymeleaf.org/Combine-th-each-with-templating-element-td4026133.html)

Answer (score 0):

th:include is what you are looking for. The code below works for me. I prefer to put multiple fragments in one file so I've included that here.

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="product : ${products}" th:include="/fragments/productFragment :: productRow" />
</table>
...

/fragments/productFragment.html
...
<tr th:fragment="productRow">
    <td th:text="${product.productName}">product name</td>
    <td th:text="${product.productPrice}">product price</td>
</tr>
...
```