# Can I use th:each without table just to repeat the same block of code for every element?

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

For example, if I want this HTML to be repeated for every element, where H4 and p tags should be filled with info from the object, is it possible?
I've seen only implementations with a table.

```
<div class="single-menu">
      <div class="myContainer">
        <button id="decrement" onclick="stepper(this)">-</button>
        <input
          type="number"
          min="0"
          max="100"
          step="1"
          value="0"
          id="my-input"
          readonly
        />
        <button id="increment" onclick="stepper(this)">+</button>
      </div>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="" />
      <div class="menu-content">
        <h4>chicken fried salad <span>$45</span></h4>
        <p>
          Aperiam tempore sit,perferendis numquam repudiandae porro
          voluptate dicta saepe facilis.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sure, it's possible.

Comment: Yes you can. You might want to put the repeating HTML in a fragment with parameters. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16818908/combine-theach-with-templating-element-using-thymeleaf for an example.